# Runtime of sorted() on an already sorted list?

Tags: python

Just curious, will the built-in `sorted()` function just note a list is already sorted and return the same list in constant time?

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = sorted(x)
```

Comment: how should it take note of that?

Comment: It could sort it and compare with the original...

Comment: @doctorlove and how would that be done in constant time? In my opinion it will be O(n) at best

Comment: Exactly. Just to walk through n numbers won't be constant time. It will be O(n), so I think the answer has to be no.

Comment: @doctorlove Agreed!

Comment: Theoretically, one could set a flag for a sorted list. But nobody would do this for a general application.

Comment: Where will the flag go?

Comment: I meassured the time for a 10k list with random numbers. Unsorted it takes 2.8 ms, sorted 185 µs. A list of 5 numbers took 405 ns, 394 ns, unsorted and sorted, respectively.The answer is no.

Comment: [Tim-sort in its best case, which occurs when the input is already sorted, it runs in **linear time**, meaning that it is an adaptive sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Analysis).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thats the algorithm complexity, not the algorithm implementation complexity. Just seeing if the list is sorted would "add" O(n) complexity to the best case scenario.

Comment: @Adirio Agreed, exactly my point. CPython will have to follow these rules at least. As a list doesn't know about whether it is sorted or not, the `sorted()` function will take at least `O(N)` time to figure it out.

Comment: `sorted()` is always expected to return a new list, if it returns the same list then `x` and `y` both will end up pointing to the same list object. Let's say if the implementation did what you expect it to do, then `sorted()` will result in ambiguous behaviour based on input list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. It will create a new list and add the values from the existing list in sorted order which in your case is already sorted. It will walk through the entire existing list in `O(n)` times for a list of length `n`. So it will not return a list in constant time.

And there is no way the `sorted()` function can know that list is sorted until the entire list is iterated over by it which obviously cannot be done in constant time.

Comment: Damn, you were quicker than me. Nice answer btw

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to determine if a list is sorted in constant time, so no.

Theoretically, a list could have a boolean attribute called sorted that gets set to False each time the list is modified and set to True when it gets sorted. This is a very bad idea for a general list type. Consider the lists [1,4,6,7] and [7,6,4,1]. Should any of these be considered sorted? Which one or both?

Comment: Albeit being a terrible idea for general purpouse lists, it may be applyable in specific scenarios, where you have full control of the list. This will force you to update the boolean flag every time you modify the list in any way (including inserting and ordering and other modifications). This could be implemented with context managers that certify that when exiting the boolean will be set to the right value. I still think this needs to be a **VERY** specific scenario.